# Calculating a continuous variable with regression trees

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cart

I have sample records with several attributes (predictors) and a predicted variable Yes/No.

What I need is, given new data that *omits* the column Yes/No, to know what is the *probability* of Yes. Note that the predicted data is a continuous variable.

I tried to use a regression tree to calculate the probability, however as I understand it, I also need the probability in the original (training) records and I don't have it. Is there a way to achieve this with regression trees? Or I need to use a different model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s what logistic regression is trying to do. Based on your predictors, $x$, the output models the conditional probability, $p(y=1|x)$. A random forest also tries to model the conditional expectation, $E[Y|X=x]$, which is also equal to this conditional probability since $Y$ is binary.

Comment: With regard to random forest, you mean that the tree will predict Yes/No and the forest the probability?

Comment: RandomForestRegressor will predict a value between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: According to Scikit RandomForestRegressor documentation  `The predicted regression target of an input sample is computed as the mean predicted regression targets of the trees in the forest.` why are you saying that it will predict a value between 0 and 1? The mean could have any value.

Comment: But, your target is between $0$ and $1$.